# Why is the defined list sorted after list sort from the another class method?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm confused with this implementation, I have simply written this list sorting code snippet to demonstrate my confusion problem. I have a list called `numberList` which consists of 4 numbers. And I'm passing

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 10, 4540, 32, 989 };

        SortClass sortClass = new();

        sortClass.Sort(numberList);

        foreach (int number in numberList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + number);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I have another class called `SortClass` which consists of simple `Sort()` method to sort the list which taking from the `Main()` method and also it's adding another two values the list.

```
public class SortClass
{
    public void Sort(List<int> list)
    {
        list.Sort();
        list.Add(1000000);
        list.Add(2000000);
    }
}
```

The above code give me following output.

```
 10
 32
 989
 4540
 1000000
 2000000
```

Can some one please explain why this output coming? I'm not returning the sorted list to the main method here, but initially defined `numberList` list has been sorted and another two integers are there which I added from the Sort method. how is this happening?

Comment: You need to read up on how reference types (classes) and value types (structures) work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>` is refernce type.

You're passing reference to the object, not the object, to `Sort` method.

Then this object is modified in `Sort` method, that's why you see such results.

[Some further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)